# Xcode 6.01 and iOS 8 do not get the location updates

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager, xcode6

My location based apps that were working fine with even up to Xcode 6 GM seed and iOS 7 after updating to Xcode 6.01 and iOS 8 cannot access location anymore. I keep going to phone's privacy settings and location and change the status for the app being developed to Always (meaning allow location access all the time). But when I go back it's blank and the app does not receive the location updates. The error is kCLErrorLocationUnknown. Anybody knows the solution?

Update: It might be that I need to call requestWhenInUseAuthorization. I have not tried it yet. I am just updating this post as I go through solutions. Maybe I should have waited before asking this here.

Comment: nah, asking earlier is fine. are you sure you have gps turned on in the main settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in info.plist and calling [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] fixed my problem.

Comment: I think you are right, I saw that in the documentation but was wrapping up so didn't get the chance to try. Will try later and let you know. Thanks!